# How do I get the latest block using etherscan api?

Tags: etherscan, blocks

I'm trying to get the latest block (it's height) using [Ethereum Developer APIs of etherscan](https://etherscan.io/apis).

For example, I can get it from blockcypher using the following URL:
https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main

(see the field "height")

Couldn't find a way to get this data from etherscan, is there and I'm missing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Get the number of the latest block using:

   https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_blockNumber&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
2. get the block using:

   https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=block&action=getblockreward&blockno=2165403&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

   change blockno='value obtained from the previous step'

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

Even easier:

https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main

Blockcypher is a pretty good api for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get the current timestamp from code (if you use python: current_timestamp = time.time()), then use the following URL:

https://api.etherscan.io/api
?module=block
&action=getblocknobytime
&timestamp=1578638524
&closest=before
&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

replace 1578638524 with the current_timestamp you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest block with just one call:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getBlockByNumber&tag=latest&boolean=true&apikey=YourApiKeyToken